# Security Framework for Java Swing Applications

Tags: java, swing, security, desktop-application

Is there a security Framework available for Java Desktop Applications? When I searched on google I saw persons talking about Spring Security, however it seems to be chiefly web-based. I have been using ordinary java code(Login forms, jdbc) to implement User Level security but I am not comfortable programming this way. Thanks for your assistance

Comment: When it is desktop applications (means no data transfer over wire), why you are concerned?I know still some ways people can get info (like keystrokes) but then you are in bigger ocean right?

Comment: Security framework seems rather generic. Security in what regard? What are your concerns?

Comment: It is a simple stand-alone Desktop Application. Basically, I only need to disable/enable options(buttons, links) based on the user that is logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have decided to use Apache Shiro Security Framework.  [It is very easy to use and the website host good documentation](http://shiro.apache.org/). Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

you can still use rolebased access and  some sort of directory service for desktop applications and you could do that with spring it's not necessarily only for web access. not that i'm pushing spring specifically.

regards

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to really answer you without knowing what threat model you're thinking of.

- Do you doubt that the signed in user has permission to open your application?
- Does the application talk to a server and get data from there?
- Are you concerned with the user tampering with code?

In the first case, this seems like something that is better handled with OS level permissions.

In the second case, handle your security on the server, you can't trust the client anyway.

In the third case, good luck.

Comment: It is a simple stand-alone Desktop Application. Basically, I only  need to disable/enable options(buttons, links) based on the user that is logged in.